# After first click of radio button can not fire change event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My jquery change event of radio button not working after first click and does not give any error please help me. i stuck in this from last week.and also cant count proper value because of this problem.

```
$('input[name="emailing"]').change(function() 
{ 
    checkValue();

});
function checkValue(evt) {

    alert('hi');
    var package = $("#package_value").val();
    var emailing = $('input[name="emailing"]:checked').val();
    $('input[name="emailing"]').on("mousedown", function() {
           var select = $('input[name="emailing"]:checked').val();
           $("#selected").val(select);
        }).on("mouseup", function() {
            $('input[name="emailing"]').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).prop('checked', true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        });
    var selected = $("#selected").val();
    alert(selected);    
    var update = $("#update").val();
    if(update != '')
    {
        var hiddenPackage = $("#hidden_pricing").val();
        var hiddenRadion = $("#hidden_radio").val();
        var totalValue = package - hiddenRadion;
        if(emailing == 1)
        {
            $("#package_value").val('');
            var value = Number(totalValue) + 38; 
            $("#package_value").val(value);
            $("#hidden_package").val(value);      
        }
        if(emailing == 2) 
        {
            $("#package_value").val('');

            var value = Number(totalValue) + 55; 
            $("#package_value").val(value);
            $("#hidden_package").val(value);      
        }   
        if(emailing == 0) 
        {
            $("#package_value").val('');
            var value =  Number(totalValue) + 0; 
            $("#package_value").val(value);
            $("#hidden_package").val(value);      
        }        
    }   
}
```

Comment: Add jquery min file in your html code. then it will work

Comment: Can you just try to edit your selector like this to trigger the event  pls : $(document).on('change','input[name="emailing"]',function(event){ checkValue(); });

Comment: I do not recommend adding a click event to the document as suggested above, but you could try changing your event to .on('click', function instead, I've had some issues with this previously. Also, it is intentional that you are only adding further events to the radio button after a change event? And relying on mouseup/down events seems like a bad idea. You can pass the value of the radio button into checkValue from the change event.

Comment: It is already included but still not working.

Comment: But I want previously checked radio button value that's why i am calling mouse up down event. if you have other idea for that then tell.its pleasure to me.

Comment: Can you explain why are you adding `mousedown` and `mouseup` event on `input[name=emailing]` in `checkValue()`?

Comment: Previously checked meaning? How many radios do you have? It looks like you are on change, adding an event that on mouse up will get the value for emailing then set the selected value to that, then on mouse down will make emailing checked and set the selected value to that. Which means that after the change event you're just resetting the emailing value to checked? You must also realise that the checkValue code will run immediately after the change event, but the mouse events will not. This means that it's likely that your selected value will be undefined at some point.

Comment: i have three radio buttons and i want previously checked radio buttons value on change of radio

Comment: you should get into the habit of accepting answers. It marks the questions as solved and you gain rep points also

Answer (score 1):

You should use delegate

```
$(document).delegate( "input[name='emailing']", "change", function() {
  checkValue();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use on() function with any element id instead of (document)

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="emailing"]', function() {
   checkValue();
});
```